# 'PublishAsync' missing in RabbitMq package

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CreateActivity command)
        {
            command.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            command.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

            await _busClient.PublishAsync(command);

            return Accepted($"activities/{command.Id}");

        }
```

It seems like 'PublishAsync' method is missing in RabbitMq. This is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RawRabbit" Version="2.0.0-beta8" />
    <PackageReference Include="RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection" Version="2.0.0-beta8" />
    <PackageReference Include="RawRabbit.Operations.Subscribe" Version="2.0.0-beta8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It is the same with all other stable versions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit/tree/664763d7cdea9d4f667cc6e1c4901ca7ab8039da/src/RawRabbit.Operations.Publish) it seems that the `PublishAsync` method is defined as an extension method in the [RawRabbit.Operations.Publish](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RawRabbit.Operations.Publish) NuGet pacakge:

> Enrich the BusClient with PublishAsync, used to perform a BasicPublish